# Trying to implement a trie data structure in java

Tags: java, data-structures, trie

I am trying to make a TrieNode class. Every node has a letter, links(the other nodes it connects to), a boolean declaring if this node marks the end of a full word, and I am trying to add another boolean saying weather it is part of a valid prefix. The part I am having trouble with is the prefix part. I am trying to make an isValidPrefix method.

My TrieNode class:

```
class TrieNode
{
    char letter;
    TrieNode[] links;
    boolean fullWord;
    boolean validPrefix;

    TrieNode(char letter)
    {
        this.letter = letter;
        links = new TrieNode[26];
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++){//i keep getting a nullPointer exception
            this.links[i].validPrefix=false;
        }
        this.fullWord = false;
        this.validPrefix=true;
    }
}
```

In my add method, every time I add a node, I set that nodes `validPrefix` to true.

My is valid prefix method:

```
 public boolean isValidPrefix(TrieNode root, String word) {
    int length = word.length();
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
    TrieNode curNode = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        curNode = curNode.links[letters[i]-97];
    }
    return curNode.validPrefix;//get a nullPointerException
}
```

Here is my add method for reference

```
    public void insertWord(TrieNode root, String word){//97 is ascii value
    int length = word.length();
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
    TrieNode curNode = root;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (curNode.links[letters[i]-97] == null)
            curNode.links[letters[i]-97] = new TrieNode(letters[i]);
        curNode = curNode.links[letters[i]-97];
        curNode.validPrefix=true;
    }
    curNode.fullWord = true;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root TrieNode[] links is instantiated with new TrieNode[26]; but those 26 are not assigned with valid object.
 
How about the below?

```
for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
         TrieNode obj = new TrieNode();
                  obj.validPrefix=false;
        this.links[i] = obj;
    }
```

Comment: i tried that earlier and still got a null pointer exception in the isvalid method

Comment: I dont think you will get NLPE after pre initializing links and validPrefix. Could you please paste me the line ??

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at PrefixTree.isValidPrefix(PrefixTree.java:84)
(line 84 is in the isValidPrefix method, the return statement at the bottom)

Comment: Thank you. My only question is how much less efficient will it make the trie ?

Comment: When i load my dictionary i get a stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out, i just check if the node is null or not:

```
public static boolean isValidPrefix(TrieNode root, String word){
    int length = word.length();
    char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        root = root.links[letters[i]-97];
    }
    if(root==null)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```